# How can I make webview use the HTML5 cache manifest?

Tags: android, webview

On Android devices up to and including 4.4.2, the default Browser and Chrome support the HTML5 cache manifest. However, on those same devices, the WebView component does not seem to support the HTML5 cache manifest. Does anybody know how I can make the WebView component support the HTML5 manifest?

Comment: I found the result here: http://alex.tapmania.org/?p=110

Comment: Probably the most non-intuitive aspect I took away from the posted solution is that you have to manually set the appCachePath of the WebView, or it won't work. You won't know why it didn't work. It just won't.

Comment: I really don't get where this is too localized

Comment: I just encountered this issue. It would be good to have an approved answer - I disagree with the closure.

Comment: If I remember correctly (as this was a while ago), you should also make sure the file path you set also exists. It appeared that some devices worked when the folder didn't exist and some devices did work (that may have also been caused by different versions of Android). Just a thought.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer of a similar question.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11684044/3181595

Answer (score 1):

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

// Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);

// This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
// But it didn't work for me without this line
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8)` is depricated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void enableHTML5AppCache() {

          webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

          // Set cache size to 8 mb by default. should be more than enough
          webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);

          // This next one is crazy. It's the DEFAULT location for your app's cache
          // But it didn't work for me without this line
          webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
          webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
          webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

          webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    }
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jaydeepw/3594828) the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
 public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
      String description, String failingUrl)
  {
    // The magic redirect
    if( "http://HTML5app.com/app/".equals(failingUrl) ) {
      // main.html is the place we are redirected to by the server if we are online
      mWebView.loadUrl("http://HTML5app.com/app/main.html");

     return;
   }
   else if( "http://HTML5app.com/app/main.html".equals(failingUrl) ) {
     // The cache failed - We don't have an offline version to show
     // This code removes the ugly android's "can't open page"
     // and simply shows a dialog stating we have no network
     view.loadData("", "text/html", "UTF-8");
     showDialog(DIALOG_NONETWORK);
   }
 }
```

Above method will be used to handle redirection in offline scenario. [For implementing appcache and path refer previous comment.

Reference Link : [HTML5 Cache mechanism in android](http://unusual.life/page5/)